# tweak how to config cydia after install package back to cydia

Tags: theos, cydia, tweak

tweak how to config cydia after install package back to cydia, not restart springboard

[restart springboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Rng.jpg)

[back to cydia, here is my wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWqtc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix mine question and add postrm shell

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a cydia
cydia=($CYDIA)
if [[ ${CYDIA+@} ]]; then
    eval "echo 'finish:open' >&${cydia[0]}"
else
    echo "uninstall completed!"

fi
exit 0
```